# Scala : Method overloading and type inference

Tags: scala

I cannot understand why Scala is not able to infer an overloaded method's arguments :

```
object A {
    implicit object SequenceMarker
    implicit object IntMarker

    def b(f: Int => Seq[Int])(implicit ev: SequenceMarker.type) = 0
    def b(f: Int => Int)(implicit ev: IntMarker.type) = 0

    def c() = { b(i => i + 1) } // this doesn't compile
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get the following error :

```
error: missing parameter type
    def c() = { b(i => i + 1) }
```

I've made some investigation using `javap` and `scala -print` and figure out that the previous code cannot be compiled without specifying what `i` is :

```
object A {
    ...
    def c() = { b((i: Int) => i + 1) }
}
```

Why is that so ? Is there any other way to overload a method while not specifying its argument's type during the call ?

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**

I've noticed using `scala -print` :

```
@SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class anonfun$c$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp with Serializable {
    final def apply(i: Int): Int = anonfun$c$1.this.apply$mcII$sp(i);
    <specialized> def apply$mcII$sp(i: Int): Int = i.+(1);
    final <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object): Object = scala.Int.box(anonfun$c$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
    def <init>(): <$anon: Function1> = {
      anonfun$c$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
```

that the argument seems to be casted in some way:

```
scala.Int.box(anonfun$c$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)))
```

This line changes depending on the argument's type :

```
scala.Int.box(anonfun$c$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
...
scala.Int.box(anonfun$c$1.this.apply(v1.$asInstanceOf[String]()))
```

which would explain why the type is required. Here is the whole log :

```
package <empty> {
  object A extends Object {
    def b(f: Function1, ev: A$SequenceMarker.type): Int = 0;
    def b(f: Function1, ev: A$IntMarker.type): Int = 0;
    def c(): Int = A.this.b({
      (new <$anon: Function1>(): Function1)
    }, A$IntMarker);
    def <init>(): A.type = {
      A.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  object A$SequenceMarker extends Object {
    def <init>(): A$SequenceMarker.type = {
      A$SequenceMarker.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  object A$IntMarker extends Object {
    def <init>(): A$IntMarker.type = {
      A$IntMarker.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  };
  @SerialVersionUID(value = 0) final <synthetic> class anonfun$c$1 extends scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1$mcII$sp with Serializable {
    final def apply(i: Int): Int = anonfun$c$1.this.apply$mcII$sp(i);
    <specialized> def apply$mcII$sp(i: Int): Int = i.+(1);
    final <bridge> <artifact> def apply(v1: Object): Object = scala.Int.box(anonfun$c$1.this.apply(scala.Int.unbox(v1)));
    def <init>(): <$anon: Function1> = {
      anonfun$c$1.super.<init>();
      ()
    }
  }
}
```

Therefore, what I want to achieve cannot be done in the way previously described. Any other idea ?

**UPDATE 2**

I've also tried :

```
def c() = { b(_ + 1) }
```

but I get another error

```
error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => x$1.$plus(1))
    def c() = { b(_ + 1) }
```

When I comment the first `b(f: Int => Seq[Int])`, it compiles well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because for purposes of overload resolution, arguments are typed without an expected type, so there is no information about what function is expected.

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#overloading-resolution

The compiler doesn't care that the set of possible overloads includes only methods that take an Int.

Comment: So this is what the following generated code means right ?  `A.this.b({ (new <$anon: Function1>(): Function1) }, A$IntMarker);` (5th line of the previous log)

Comment: What do you mean by "mean"? I'm not sure the -print output is very helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you mean with "arguments are typed without an expected type, so there is no information about what function is expected". Could you please give more details ? I've read the link above, but it sounds a bit obscure to me. Is it about how functions are expanded ?

Comment: Simply, to type `_ + 1` you have to know the type of the function expected, which is normally the param type of the method you're calling, `f(_ + 1)`. But if the method is overloaded, you have to type the arg without knowing the param type, because you haven't decided which method is getting called yet.

Comment: Ok, so basically, `_ + 1` expands to `Function<?, Int>` in this case, which prevents the compiler to figure which method should be used. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: `(_: String) + 1` is `Function[String, String]`, as a counterexample. So `_ + 1` means nothing by itself.